# Horizontal flickering bands on GeForce 560 Ti

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, black-screen-of-death

My 5 year old graphics card started showing problems since yesterday - screen has multiple flickering black lines always, even during boot up (so rules out a Windows 10 problem).
I still updated the drivers to the latest version as of this writing (382.53), then I got a black screen with nothing after boot up. Now my computer only boots up using the built in Windows driver. Even with that, the flickering lines persist.

The Windows event log shows errors in `nvlddmkm`. So is my graphics card toast, or is there a fix for this?

Answer (score -1):

Try your card in another mobo, but I'm almost sure that your GPU is burned.